# I tried using cy.wrap() since click() was not working for autosugession, however still the desired option is still not being selected

Tags: jquery, testing, visual-studio-code, automation, cypress

I am trying to select the country New Zealand from the autosuggestion. I tried using `$el.trigger("click");` as well but it is not working.

```
it("select all tours location in the homepage", () => {
        cy.visit("https://www.bookmundi.com/"); //homepage
        cy.get('#atours-trigger').click({force:true})
        cy.get('#where-going').type('New');
      //  cy.get('#where-going').click();
        cy.waitUntil(() => true);

        cy.get('#suggestion-div>ul>li>div>*').each(($el, index, $list) => {
            const prod = $el.text();
            const productToSelect = 'New Zealand';
            if(prod == productToSelect) {
                cy.wrap($el.find('a')).click({force:true});               
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait on the "New Zealand" suggestion with a `.should()`

```js
cy.visit("https://www.bookmundi.com/"); //homepage
cy.get('#atours-trigger').click({force:true})
cy.get('#where-going').type('New');

cy.contains('#suggestion-div div.item-list', 'New Zealand')
  .should('be.visible')                              // wait up to 4s
  .click()
```

I think what happens is

- `cy.waitUntil(() => true)` doesn't do much waiting
- `.each()` is grabbing the list items before it's fully populated

Answer (score 0):

If you use the XPath extension, you can achieve the same result with less code.

```js
cy.visit("https://www.bookmundi.com/");
cy.get('#atours-trigger').click({ force: true })
cy.get('#where-going').type('New Zealand');
cy.xpath('(//a[contains(text(), "New Zealand")])[1]').click({ force: true })
```

Note that in order to use XPath, you must install it using the command: `npm install -D cypress-xpath` and then include in your project `cypress/support/index.js` this line
`require('cypress-xpath')`.

You can find more details about installation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-xpath

Comment: That's clicking the wrong place. It's hitting the "Top Destinations" entry (not visible), not the Suggestions list. Take out the `{force:true}` and it fails.

Comment: The result is the same after the search button it's clicked, you are redirected to https://www.bookmundi.com/new-zealand

Comment: No, if you select a suggestion you are then asked for the dates. Your code tests a different part of the web page. Even if you happened to hit the right link, the selector is too vague. If the order of links changes then your test becomes flaky.

Comment: Also I'd question why you need to add a plugin to do this, the standard Cypress commands do the job.